# d3: how to interpolate a string (with numbers in it) so that the numbers don't get interpolated

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm a newbie in javascript but a few weeks back just delved into d3.js trying
to create a spatio-temporal visualisation.

What I want to achieve is something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/dmatekenya/mz5fxd44/) based on code shown below:

```
var w1 = ["Dunstan","Mercy","Lara","Khama"];
var w2 =["August 1,2013","August 2,2013","August 3,2013"]
var text = d3.select("body")
            .attr("fill","red")
            .text("Dunstan")
            .attr("font-size", "50px");  
var j = 0;
var transition = function() {
return text.transition().duration(500).tween("text", function() {
   var i = d3.interpolateString(w1[j], w1[j + 1]);
   return function(t) {
    this.textContent = i(t);
  };
}).each('end', function() {
  j += 1;
  if (!(j > w1.length)) return transition();
});
};
transition();
```

However, instead I want to use date string ( like *w2* in the code snippet above). When I do this d3 interpolates the numbers embedded in the string as well and the output isn't what I'm looking for. I need help on how I can somehow create a custom interpolator which can interpolate date string while ignoring numbers in them. I know from d3 documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#tween) thats its possible to push a custom interpolator into the d3 array of interpolators but I have tried and still cannot get it to work.

Kindly need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `d3.scaleQuantize()`.

For instance:

```
var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(["brown", "steelblue"]);

color(0.49); // "brown"
color(0.51); // "steelblue"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, since its been a while since I asked this question and not working with d3.js as much anymore, its hard for me to accept this answer.